# How to find the minimum spanning tree by cycle finding?

Tags: algorithm

By searching the web I can find 2(kruskal and prims) algorithm for finding minimum spanning tree. But this algorithm

```
   *let T be initially the set of all edges
       *while there is some cycle C in T
         remove edge e from T where e has the heaviest weight in C
```

I can't find by searching the web. How do I implement this algorithm. How can I find every possible cycle?

Comment: [Cycle detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection_(graph_theory)#Cycle_detection). But this algorithm is a lot more expensive than Kruskal's and Prim's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the edges by decreasing order, then try to delete an edge each time. Check whether the graph is connected or not. If the graph is still connected after deleting an edges, it will guarantee that the edge is in a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this would be through the Union-Find data structure (see link below). Checking for cycles can be done in O(1) time and adding a new edge takes on average O(log V) processing per node, requiring an overall run-time of O(E + V log V). We can use more advanced data structures to achieve near linear time bounds.

http://people.cs.umass.edu/~barring/cs611/lecture/7.pdf